# How to make NSButton title at bottom and centered?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsbutton

How can I make a button's title at bottom and centered programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass `NSButtonCell` and override [`drawTitle:withFrame:inView:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButtonCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSButtonCell/drawTitle:withFrame:inView:)(`drawTitle(_,withFrame,inView)` in swift) to draw the title centered by manipulating `frame` parameter for example, or draw the title by yourself. Then set your button's cell class to your subclass.

Or place `NSTextField` over your button, set constraints to anchor the bottomcenter of the button and set its text to whatever you want, and keep your buttons title empty.

Unfortunately, there is no `contentHorizontalAlignment` property, like in iOS, so you have to solve it with subclass or a different UI composing.