# Justification of NSButton label

Tags: cocoa, label, alignment, nsbutton

ALL,

By default, the label of NSButton is centered on both x- and y- axis.

Is it possible to make the text label to be left-{right-,top-,bottom-}justified?

TIA!

Comment: Did you try setting `alignment`?

Comment: @Willeke, you mean something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514157/nsbutton-setalignment-does-not-work? Looking at the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextalignment?language=objc it looks like I will be able to set a horizontal alignment and not a vertical one. Is there a different way for both?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make NSButton title at bottom and centered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32424770/how-to-make-nsbutton-title-at-bottom-and-centered)